# Custom Zuul Filter - log Request Body

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a custom (pre) zuul filter, in that I want to log the requestBody of a request for an API (API is available in service which is registered with Eureka) but when I use the below code in ZUUL

`HttpServletRequest request.getReader();` or 
`RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getInputStream();`

I am able to log the requestBody but -

**Problem**:
The service which is having the API is not able to get the requestBody because its not possible to call getReader on the same request again. I understand that I need to have something which extends HttpServletRequestWrapper and override getReader() method but I am not sure how to handle in ZUUL context, how to forward the request along with requestBody to the service from ZUUL after its been logged.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by using HttpServletRequestWrapper, will post the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly wrap the incoming request in **HttpServletRequestWrapper** instance. Here is the sample code. Hope this helps.

```
package com.example.edge.filter.pre;

import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Component
public class RequestPayloadLoggingFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestPayloadLoggingFilter.class);

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(ctx.getRequest());

        log.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));

        String requestData = null;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject requestJson = null;

        try {
            if (request.getContentLength() > 0 ) {
                requestData = CharStreams.toString(request.getReader());
            }

            if (requestData == null) {
                return null;
            }
            requestJson = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(requestData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error parsing JSON request", e);
            return null;
        }
        log.info(String.format("%s request payload %s", request.getMethod(), requestJson.toJSONString()));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to log both the request body AND the response of an API call through a Zuul gateway? Seems like I can log either the request or the response, but not both, in the same filter. I'd like to have something like an access log for all my API calls, including the response code.